# Controller to initialize Instances of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I've got several unrelated swing classes that are instances of JFrame.  The issue is, I'd like to be able to create a *controller* class with a static method to load the appropriate *frames* as needed. I'm experiencing difficulty with the following code as many of components are failing to load.  I suspect that the issue is with the event dispatch thread.  Below is the code that doesn't work:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Controller {

    private Controller() {
    }

    public static void initialize(final JFrame frame) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame selectionFrame = frame;
            }
        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Controller.initialize(new SampleFrame());

    }

}
```

The program loads the frame and toolbar components but other components fail to load.  NOTE: The program runs just fine if I refactor the Controller like so :

```
public class Controller {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new SampleFrame();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Post your SampleFrame class

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)